# Shared drive accessed in windows via sshfs not showing certain large directories

Tags: ubuntu, windows, sshfs, shared-folders

I've just set up an Ubuntu 18.04 server, and mapped its drive to my windows notebook using [sshfs-win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win). This works for the most part -- I can read and write to most locations on the drive. However, certain directories which are filled with thousands of files or subdirectories show up as empty when accessed from the windows machine. I am able to create a directory and put a few files in it and it works fine, but as soon as I try to copy in the large library I'm trying to store, all files disappear, including those I could see previously.

Everything always displays correctly on the linux side. Permissions on the directory are set to drwxrwxr-x, and trying to change permissions of the drive via Windows security options gives an access denied error.

How can I get these files to show up on the network drive?

EDIT: Solved below. Better question would be "Please enlighten me on the finer points of how unix and windows differ in their interpretation of '\' characters, and how can I get artists not to include '\' characters in their album titles?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the error. Couple of stray files with special characters in their names worked fine on unix, but broke everything in their folder when viewed on windows. Mistakenly correlated this to overall file count in my question, as the small-scale test samples I took from my database didn't display this error. Sanitizing auto-gen file names fixed everything.